# How to stream tweets based on a list without Retweets

Tags: python, api, twitter, stream, tweepy

I am trying to stream tweets based on when certain people post through Streaming in tweepy.
When I run the following code, I get Retweets mixed within the data. Is there any way to pull users tweets in real-time without retweets?

```
    with open('twitter_list.txt') as user_list:
        usernames = user_list.read().splitlines()
    print('usernames', usernames)
    ids = [api.get_user(screen_name= username).id_str for username in usernames]
    print('ids', ids)

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth,

                            MyListener(raw_file=raw_file, csv_file=csv_file, text_file=text_file, max_num=num_tweets))

    twitter_stream.filter(track=key_words, follow=ids)
```

Comment: no, the API will return Retweets as well - you will need to discard them in your code.

Comment: @AndyPiper I found that this is exactly what I need: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule  Would this be compatible with my python code?

Comment: I do not think that Tweepy supports the new streaming filter endpoint for v2 yet, but it is being worked on.